# Change Material Table Column According to The Drop down Value In Table row React js

Tags: reactjs, material-table

What I Have

- I'm using "material-table": "1.67.1" [sample image for show what I

  need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNUDP.png)

What I Need to Do

- I need to change columns in the table when i select dog from the drop
  down already in the table using react js. as an example when i select
  Dog i need to allow user to edit only two columns and when i select
  cat i need to allow user to edit only one column.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

I used editComponent prop in material table with dropdown and then I used it's on change method to do the above task.